# Unconfirmed Transactions - 4days - Help Needed To Accelerate

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

I need help to confirm the 2 transactions below for me.

ccc57c3f373d74bd20aeac555998ade561f726d6ccd3f85851a2d8ab892eae44

21047d289a7f7fcd19eddbe8504dd1bb9b2e233cb26a2c9a74e0f3529c2a0795

It has been holding for so many days now.

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the free ViaBTC Transaction Accelerator service (requires a minimum fee rate of 0.0001 BTC/kB): "https://pool.viabtc.com" under "Tool" ?